# Bash script to ftp only files of type gz in current directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a bash script that cd to the right directory then uses the mput command to ftp all the files in the directory to a remote server, as below:

```
for from_dir in $DATE_LIST 
do
    cd ${FILE_LANDING_DIR}/deltas/${from_dir}
    ftp_files
done

ftp_files () {
    ftp -inv $HOST <<-EOF > $LOG_DIR/tempftplog
    user $USER $PASS 
    cd ${ID_LANDING_DIR}
    mput *
    bye 
    EOF
}
```

I tried altering the ftp_files function to ftp only the `.gz` files in that directory by changing the line from `mput *` to `mput *.gz` but that did not work.

Can someone tell me how I can do this once in the ftp command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `mput *.gz` not work? If not, try the ftp `glob` command first.

http://man.cx/ftp

Answer (score -3):

What about performing a directory search and piping it to the mput?

```
ls *.gz | mput
```

I cannot test this right now because Im not at a linux box so it might need to be tweaked to get it to work 100% correctly.